# AR core for android

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore, android-augmented-reality

I have planned to integrate AR into my android app. I'm new to AR and confused whether to choose ARCore for Android studio (Java) or Unity.
Please suggest me a good option to get started with AR using ARCore.

Answer (score 0):

Its sounds like you are familiar with Android Apps, so looking at the ARCore sample 'HelloSceneform' would almost certainly be the easiest way to start.

This uses 'SceneForm' which is a high level API/framework to render objects on detected planes - it basically does a lot of the low level leg work for you.

This will allow you run the sample and then modify it to get a feel how it works.

The instructions are really quite straightforward and are available here at the time of writing:

- https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/quickstart

Comment: Thank you very much for you suggestion 